# What does "This query could run faster with more shuffle" means in the BigQuery Query insights?

Tags: google-bigquery, query-optimization

I am working on a task for optimising a BigQuery SQL in order to improve the query performance. Me and my co-worker noticed that it shuffles a huge amount of data during the interim steps.
After some amount of effort, we were able to improve the query performance by 5-60%.
The way we achieved it was to eliminate some columns for reducing the shuffle bytes in the middle of stages.

After we tested the query, we saw that there is a weird tip in the Query Insights of the Job Reuslt:

[image]

I was so confused when I saw the message.
It even sounds against the physics to me. Usually more shuffle means more runtime.
Does anybody know what this tip means?

I tried searching the message in the official documents and also googled for some time but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry the message is a bit confusing, we will looking into improving documentation.

When you run jobs on BigQuery, you have a limited amount of shuffle quota that jobs can use. This message says that you may need more for query to run faster. You could:

1. If you are using on-demand pricing, buying slots should give you dedicated shuffle quota
2. If you are using flat-rate pricing, buying more slots will increase your shuffle quota.

See more in public documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-insights#insufficient_shuffle_quota

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, the "shuffle" refers to the process of redistributing data between workers during a query. It is used to ensure that each worker has the data it needs to process its part of the query.

If the BigQuery Query Insights panel indicates that a query could run faster with more shuffle, it means that the query is currently using less shuffle than what BigQuery estimates would be optimal for the given query and data. This could potentially lead to slower performance because the workers may not have all the data they need to process the query efficiently.

Comment: How can I control the shuffle?

Comment: Based on Alexey's answer and the other documentation that I've read, wouldn't the insight message indicate the opposite of what you suggest? As in, the message means that you are using too much shuffle and may want to either optimize your query or consider upgrading your payment model.